# c++ winhttp/wininet wrapper to post forms and upload files without mfc/atl

Tags: c++, file, post, wininet, winhttp

could somebody point me to a winhttp/wininet based c++ wrapper which would not require mfc/atl? So that I might get it to work in MSVC express.

I'd like to be able to use GET, POST and upload files too through HTML-form.

I've checked several in codeproject.com but had trouble finding a suitable wrapper.

Is there something that could help me?

Comment: You can work around MSVC express's limitations by loading the Wininet.dll at run time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You can contact me via my gmail account CodingWithMetta if you want more help or if you wish to collaborate on the project you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

Here I made you one to get you started. If you are using a MSVC you should learn how to dig down through dll's and find exported functions. [DLL Export Viewer is what I used for this.](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) You'll need to find where wininet.dll is located on your machine and alter the code accordingly. I hope this helps. So here is my WinInetRTW class (Run Time Wrapper).

```
// wininetrtw.h

#ifndef WININETRTW_H
#define WININETRTW_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>

typedef HINTERNET (__cdecl *HttpOpenRequestFuncPtr)(HINTERNET, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, DWORD, DWORD);
typedef HINTERNET (__cdecl *InternetConnectFuncPtr)(HINTERNET, LPCTSTR, INTERNET_PORT, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD_PTR);
typedef HINTERNET (__cdecl *InternetOpenFuncPtr)(LPCTSTR, DWORD, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, DWORD);
typedef HINTERNET (__cdecl *InternetOpenUrlFuncPtr)(HINTERNET, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD_PTR);
typedef BOOL (__cdecl *InternetReadFileFuncPtr)(HINTERNET, LPVOID, DWORD, LPDWORD);

class WinInetRTW {

public:
    WinInetRTW();
    ~WinInetRTW();

    // WinInet functions
    bool LoadLibrary(std::string&);
    bool HttpOpenRequest(HINTERNET hConnect, LPCTSTR lpszVerb, LPCTSTR lpszObjectName, LPCTSTR lpszVersion, LPCTSTR lpszReferer, LPCTSTR *lplpszAcceptTypes, DWORD dwFlags, DWORD_PTR dwContext);
    bool InternetConnect(HINTERNET hInternet, LPCTSTR lpszServerName, INTERNET_PORT nServerPort, LPCTSTR lpszUsername, LPCTSTR lpszPassword, DWORD dwService, DWORD dwFlags, DWORD_PTR dwContext);
    bool InternetOpen(LPCTSTR lpszAgent, DWORD dwAccessType, LPCTSTR lpszProxyName, LPCTSTR lpszProxyBypass, DWORD dwFlags);
    bool InternetOpenUrl(HINTERNET, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD_PTR);
    bool InternetReadFile(HINTERNET, LPVOID, DWORD, LPDWORD);

    // Helper methods
    bool InternetReadFileToBuffer(HINTERNET);

    // Results from respective methods
    HINTERNET InternetOpenResult;
    HINTERNET InternetConnectResult;
    HINTERNET HttpOpenRequestResult;
    HINTERNET InternetOpenUrlResult;
    std::stringstream InternetReadFileStream;

private:
    HttpOpenRequestFuncPtr HttpOpenRequestFunc;
    InternetConnectFuncPtr InternetConnectFunc;
    InternetOpenFuncPtr InternetOpenFunc;
    InternetOpenUrlFuncPtr InternetOpenUrlFunc;
    InternetReadFileFuncPtr InternetReadFileFunc;

};

#endif // WININETRTW_H

// wininetrtw.cpp

#include "wininetrtw.h"

WinInetRTW::WinInetRTW()
{
}

WinInetRTW::~WinInetRTW()
{
}

bool WinInetRTW::LoadLibrary(std::string& PathToDll)
{
    HINSTANCE dllInstance;
    dllInstance = ::LoadLibrary(PathToDll.c_str()); // Load library

    this->HttpOpenRequestFunc = reinterpret_cast<HttpOpenRequestFuncPtr>(::GetProcAddress(dllInstance, "HttpOpenRequest")); // Load function
    this->InternetConnectFunc = reinterpret_cast<InternetConnectFuncPtr>(::GetProcAddress(dllInstance, "InternetConnectA"));
    this->InternetOpenFunc = reinterpret_cast<InternetOpenFuncPtr>(::GetProcAddress(dllInstance, "InternetOpenA"));
    this->InternetOpenUrlFunc = reinterpret_cast<InternetOpenUrlFuncPtr>(::GetProcAddress(dllInstance, "InternetOpenUrlA"));
    this->InternetReadFileFunc = reinterpret_cast<InternetReadFileFuncPtr>(::GetProcAddress(dllInstance, "InternetReadFile"));

    if(!dllInstance){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/*
 * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384363(v=vs.85).aspx
 * */
bool WinInetRTW::InternetConnect(HINTERNET hInternet, LPCTSTR lpszServerName, INTERNET_PORT nServerPort, LPCTSTR lpszUsername, LPCTSTR lpszPassword, DWORD dwService, DWORD dwFlags, DWORD_PTR dwContext)
{
    InternetConnectResult = InternetConnectFunc(hInternet, lpszServerName, nServerPort, lpszUsername, lpszPassword, dwService, dwFlags, dwContext);
    if(!InternetConnectResult){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/* 
 * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385096(v=vs.85).aspx
 * */
bool WinInetRTW::InternetOpen(LPCTSTR lpszAgent, DWORD dwAccessType, LPCTSTR lpszProxyName, LPCTSTR lpszProxyBypass, DWORD dwFlags)
{
        this->InternetOpenResult = this->InternetOpenFunc(lpszAgent, dwAccessType, lpszProxyName, lpszProxyBypass, dwFlags);
        if(!this->InternetOpenResult){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}

/*
 * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098(v=vs.85).aspx
 * */
bool WinInetRTW::InternetOpenUrl(HINTERNET hInternet, LPCTSTR lpszUrl, LPCTSTR lpszHeaders, DWORD dwHeadersLength, DWORD dwFlags, DWORD_PTR dwContext)
{
    InternetOpenUrlResult = InternetOpenUrlFunc(hInternet, lpszUrl, lpszHeaders, dwHeadersLength, dwFlags, dwContext);
    if(!InternetOpenUrlResult){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/* 
 * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385103(v=vs.85).aspx
 * */
bool WinInetRTW::InternetReadFile(HINTERNET hFile, LPVOID lpBufferOut, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesToRead, LPDWORD lpdwNumberOfBytesReadOut)
{
    return InternetReadFileFunc(hFile, lpBufferOut, dwNumberOfBytesToRead, lpdwNumberOfBytesReadOut);
}

bool WinInetRTW::InternetReadFileToBuffer(HINTERNET hFile)
{
    DWORD dwRead;
    char Buffer[1024];

    while (this->InternetReadFile(hFile, Buffer, 1023, &dwRead ) )
    {
        if ( dwRead == 0 )
            break;
        Buffer[dwRead] = 0;
        InternetReadFileStream << Buffer;
    }

    return true;
}


// main.cpp

#include "wininetrtw.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Find the path to the file on your own system.
    string PathToDll = "C:\\Windows\\winsxs\\x86_microsoft-windows-i..tocolimplementation_31bf3856ad364e35_9.4.8112.16441_none_1a52f663bc299b3d\\wininet.dll";
    WinInetRTW net;

    if(net.LoadLibrary(PathToDll)){
        cout << "Library loaded!\n";
        net.InternetOpen("InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
        if(net.InternetOpenUrl(net.InternetOpenResult, "http://www.google.com", NULL, 0, 0, 0))
        {
            net.InternetReadFileToBuffer(net.InternetOpenUrlResult);
            cout << net.InternetReadFileStream.str();
        }
    }
    else{
        cout << "Library failed to load.";
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, when you see a function like "InternetOpen" in a windows library, there are often two version. The ANSI version and the UNICODE version. In the DLL they are differentiated by appending 'A' or 'W' respectively. In the code I posted I used the ANSI version, but by changing the 'A' to a 'W' you could use the unicode version of the function.